# Laravel DB query builder update with query data

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have table `table` with fields int `field1` and  int`field2`
what I need is to update values of `field2` and make them equal to field1 + field2.
I want to use query builder so code is:

```
DB::table('table')
    ->update(['field2' => ????]);
```

How can I put sum of field1 and field2 to request?

Comment: have you tried `field1+field2` ?

Comment: as I understand they will be written like a string 'field1+field2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a raw expression:

```
DB::table('table')->update(['field2' => DB::raw('field1 + field2')]);
```

Comment: I've just found this solution myself ))